# fill in missing DataFrame indices

Tags: pandas, dataframe, union, nan, multi-index

Given two pandas dataframes `dfa` and `dfb`, how can I ensure the MultiIndex of each DataFrame contains all rows from the other?

```
In [147]: dfa
Out[147]: 
        c
a b      
0 5  10.0
1 6  11.0
2 7  12.0
3 8  13.5
4 9  14.0

In [148]: dfb
Out[148]: 
      c
a b    
0 5  10
2 7  12
3 8  13
4 9  14
```

Here, `dfb` lacks index (1, 6):

```
In [149]: dfa - dfb
Out[149]: 
       c
a b     
0 5  0.0
1 6  NaN
2 7  0.0
3 8  0.5
4 9  0.0
```

... but `dfa` may also lack indices from `dfb`. The value should be `0` where we insert a missing index in each dataframe.

In other words, each DataFrame's index should be the union of the two MultiIndexes, where the added row gets a value of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with parameter `fill_value` if need replace `NaN` to some value:

```
df = dfa.sub(dfb, fill_value=0)
print (df)
        c
a b      
0 5   0.0
1 6  11.0
2 7   0.0
3 8   0.5
4 9   0.0
```

```
df = dfb.sub(dfa, fill_value=0)
print (df)
      c
a b    
0 5  10
1 6   0
2 7  12
3 8  13
4 9  14
```

Or if need [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of indexes add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = dfa.index.union(dfb.index)
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           names=['a', 'b'],
           sortorder=0)

print (dfa.reindex(mux, fill_value=0))
        c
a b      
0 5  10.0
1 6  11.0
2 7  12.0
3 8  13.5
4 9  14.0

print (dfb.reindex(mux, fill_value=0))
      c
a b    
0 5  10
1 6   0
2 7  12
3 8  13
4 9  14
```

Answer (score 0):

For an expansion to the **full cartesian product** of all **occurring MultiIndex values** this works nicely:

```
from itertools import product

df = dfa.loc[0:2]
print(df)

        c
a b      
0 5  10.0
1 6  11.0
2 7  12.0

# build full cartesian product index
cpr_index = product(*(df.index.get_level_values(icol) for icol in df.index.names))
# and generate the missing elements, filling with -1
print(df.reindex(cpr_index, fill_value=-1))

        c
a b      
0 5  10.0
  6  -1.0
  7  -1.0
1 5  -1.0
  6  11.0
  7  -1.0
2 5  -1.0
  6  -1.0
  7  12.0
```

basically this creates a fully populated tensor or matrix filling in the default values.
for a partial full population (e.g.: for all a >= 1), the product has to be crafted accordingly.